# Rails 4 iOS Authentication and Authorization

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using Devise and CanCanCan to manage user authentication and authorization, but for some reason my current_user object is always nil Rails side even though I am getting a success message with my login. I'm not sure what the disconnect it, but I can't retrieve any resources after a successful login.

What I am looking for, though, is I would like to understand better what is going on behind the scenes. I send back the X-CSRF-Token header (form_authenticity_token) from the rails side once the user is logged in, but it was my understanding that this is only necessary to pass back to the server from my iOS app for actions that write to the server (POST, PUT, DELETE). If that is the case, then how do I identify myself to the server for GET requests?

Answer (score 2):

After a little more research, this is how I would summarize what I ended up doing.

- For GET requests, you use the cookie store built into the iOS networking libs. By default this is turned on in the NSURLRequest (and mutable variant) class. That's pretty much all you'll need for GETs. Of course you'll have to login successfully in order to get the cookie and logging in requires a POST.
- For POST, PUT, and DELETE, you do have to provide the X-CSRF-Token as a header in your requests. However, that is true for all requests except the login request which will need to disable the X-CSRF-Token header requirement in order to create the session, but more on that below.

First, here is an implementation of a login on iOS against a devise installation (with a change to the devise login route which is `<server_url>/users/login.json` instead of the default `<server_url>/users/sign_in.json`):

```
- (void)loginWithUsername:(NSString*)username
                 password:(NSString*)password
          completionBlock:(void(^)(id response, NSError *error))block
{
    NSDictionary *loginDictionary = @{@"user" : @{@"email" : username,
                                                  @"password" : password}
                                      };

    // Convert dictionary to NSData for POST body
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:loginDictionary 
                                                   options:0 
                                                     error:&error];

    NSString *postUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@users/login.json", 
                                                             kApiEndpointURL];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest 
                     requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postUrlString]
                        cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                    timeoutInterval:kTimeoutInterval];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:data];

    // This is the default--here for clarity
    [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] showNetworkActivityIndicator];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = 
                             [session dataTaskWithRequest:request 
                               completionHandler:^(NSData *data, 
                                            NSURLResponse *response, 
                                                  NSError *error) {
        // Save the token so we can perform POSTs, PUTS, and DELETEs
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
        self.xcsrfToken = httpResp.allHeaderFields[@"X-CSRF-Token"];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] hideNetworkActivityIndicator];
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@", json);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (block) {
                block(json, error);
            }
        });
    }];

    [dataTask resume];
}
```

- On the rails side, you will need to have a way to create a session without requiring the X-CSRF-Token and you will also need to pass back the X-CSRF-Token once the user has authenticated so that future write actions will succeed.

I did this with the following in my sessions controller:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    after_filter :set_csrf_header, only: [:create]
    skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:create]


    def set_csrf_header
        response.headers['X-CSRF-Token'] = form_authenticity_token
    end
end
```

My sessions controller has more in it, but this shows the pertinent parts. After the request succeeds for the create action, I send back the X-CSRF-Token. However, I skip the authenticity verification on the create. This means that while the creating the session itself doesn't require the authenticity token, it will send one back to the requester once the action has completed so the requester can then use that token in all future write actions.

If I am missing something or doing something incorrectly, please let me know and I'll update this answer.